# How To Use UserDefaults with Bool (Swift)

Tags: swift, boolean, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I am trying to leran how to use `UserDefaults` with Swift. I need to save the state of a bool statement.

I have a `UISwitch` that if it is on, the bool statement is true. If it is off, it is false. Like this:

***I declare a gloabal variable...***

```
var switchBool : Bool = false
```

***Then I set up the action for the switch...***

```
 @IBAction func boolSwitchAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if darkModeSwitch.isOn {
            switchBool = true
        } else {
            switchBool = false
        }  
    }
```

It works great. But then, once the app is shut down, the app does not remember that the switch is on, nor if the `switchBool` is true. That's why I need to use UserDeafaults. I've looked for some tutorials, but I couldn't find one that would help me. Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Where's your attempt to use UserDefaults?

Comment: @rmaddy Nothing that I tried worked.